# DTD - Switch off validation for specific XML element

Tags: xml, dtd, xmlspy

I'm writing a DTD for an XML document I create.  The XML document is a wrapper around a Payload provided by another system.  I have no control over the contents of the Payload, and don't care providing it is self-contained valid XML.  (It is ultimately validated by a separate schema I have no control over).

However, I do care about the structure of the wrapper and want to be able to dictate the structure of each Example below and control the SomeData I add.

The DTD will look something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE Examples[
<!ELEMENT Examples(Example+)>
<!ELEMENT Example(SomeData,Payload)>
<!ELEMENT SomeData (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT Payload ANY>
]>
```

The Payload will be somthing like:

```
<Payload><foo>bar</foo></Payload>
```

The problem is that whatever I drop into the Payload, XMLSpy will continue validating that and complain that the child elements of Payload are not expected:

```
Content model of element <Payload> disallows element <foo> at this position.

Element <foo> has not been declared.
```

What I want is a way to say, "everything underneath Payload is not defined as having a specific structure, so please ignore it".

I figured defining it as ANY or CDATA might work, but so such luck.

Any pointers much appreicated.

Comment: If you use XSD you can achieve this with `<xs:any processContents="skip"/>`. I don't know DTD well enough to give you an answer there without looking it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short - I don't believe this is possible in dtd.

As Michael points out in the comments it is possible in XSD.

You can use `<xs:any processContents="skip"/>` which is the answer to the original questions, but what is more useful (to me) is to use `<xs:any processContents="strict"/>` and specify a different XSD for the inner XML.

You can see my follow-up question and answer about the specifics of doing this:
[Dynamic XML Schema Validates Subsection of Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174985/dynamic-xml-schema-validates-subsection-of-document)